# Eigen equivalent of matlab's expm()

Tags: eigen

I am looking for Eigen in C++ equivalent of Matlab's expm() function.
Would anyone know how to find this?

Please see Matlab's documentation for the expm() function.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/expm.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [matrix function module](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__MatrixFunctions__Module.html):

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions>
MatrixXd A = ..., expA;
expA = A.exp();
```